# Generator of graphs with known chromatic number

Tags: ruby, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have implemented several graph coloring algorithms as a class project and I would like to test and compare their performance. For this I need test graphs with known chromatic number.

I have expected this to be quite common requirement so that there will be algorithm and/or library readily available. It turned out that I was wrong. After quite extensive search the best I found is a [paper from 1979](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/jres.084.024).¹ In section 6 there is a method for generation of graphs with known chromatic number described. Before endeavoring to translate it from math to programmers I would like to know whether there really isn’t implementation available to avoid reinventing a wheel.

---

¹ Leighton, F. T. (1979). A graph coloring algorithm for large scheduling problems. In *Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards* (pp. 489-506). http://doi.org/10.6028/jres.084.024

Comment: The (heuristic) algorithms described in Section 3 of the paper you cite would seem fairly straightforward to code. Maybe just use the first one described, which is the simplest. Readers: here the chromatic number is the minimum number of colours required to colour the nodes of a graph such that no two adjacent nodes have the same colour (e.g., no two countries having a common border are assigned the same colour on a map).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/SimpleGraphs.html and click through. Most graphs there include chromatic polys from which you can read the chromatic number.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for taking time to check the paper. I am not looking for algorithm to determine chromatic number of a graph. I would like to generate graph with given χ as described in section 6 and use it as a test target. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The majority of that algorithm is actually just creating specific type of psuedo-random number generator (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Answer (score 1):

So I don't know ruby, but came across this question when I was looking at the same paper and also confused. I've implemented the algorithm in Rust ([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ef6c1c7a947fddfce496f6303b687c7)) using the [petgraph](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.6.0/petgraph/index.html) library to represent the graphs.

But the basic idea is that you want to choose some values:

- `a`: multiplier (also called factor)
- `c`: increment
- `m`: modulus
- `x[0]`: some seed or starting value

That define a pseudo-random number generator (specifically a Linear congruential generator [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)) which is defined by the recursive relation:

```
x[i] = (x[i - 1] * a + c) % m
```

For some nice properties, we also need the parameters to meet the criteria (which Leighton mentions in the paper as the first step):

1. `m` much greater than `n` (the number of nodes)
2. `gcd(m, n) == k`
3. `gcd(m, c) == 1` or `m` and `c` are coprime
4. for any prime number `p`: if `m % p == 0` then `(a-1) % p == 0`
5. if `m % 4 == 0` then `(a-1) % 4 == 0`

I believe these criteria enable Leighton to prove that the procedure works, but I am not sure. Luckily, he provides some values for `m`, `c`, `a`, and `x[0]` in Appendix C. For example:

```rust
// Values taken from Leighton
let chromatic_number = 5;   // k
let modulus = 84_035;       // m
let increment = 6_859;      // c
let multiplier = 8_401;     // a
let mut x_i = vec![33_289]; // x[0]
```

After that, we generate a vector of random numbers `x_i` according to the recurrence relation:

```rust
let num_rand_numbers = 100;
for i in (1..num_rand_numbers) {
    // x[i] = (x[i-1] * a + c) % m
    x_i.push((x_i[i - 1] * multiplier + increment) % modulus);
}
```

So we've got random numbers `x_i`, but they're in the interval `[0, m]` and our nodes are in the range `[0, n-1]` where `m` is a lot greater than `n`. So create a vector `y_i` where:

```rust
// Construct y_i in [0, n-1] such that y_i = x_i % n
let y_i = x_i.iter()  // Convert x_i to an iterator
             .map(|x| x % num_nodes) // y_i = x_i % n
             .collect::<Vec<_>>();   // convert iterator to vector
```

So there's a lot of work just to efficiently choose some random vectors but once they're chosen, the algorithm goes like:

1. Create a new undirected graph with `num_nodes` nodes. In my testing, Leighton's method resulted in lots of islands with some nodes completely unreachable from the others. So here I connect them all in a line so that we don't have any island nodes.

```rust
let mut graph = UnGraph::new_undirected();
let mut prev;
let mut curr = graph.add_node(Node {});

for n in 1..num_nodes {
    prev = curr;
    curr = graph.add_node(Node {});
    graph.add_edge(prev, curr, Edge {});
}
```

2. Cache the node indices so we don't have to look them up every time

```rust
let node_indices = graph.node_indices().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Now define an h-clique as a set of nodes which are all fully connected to
each other, such that each node has h-1 edges coming from it.
This corresponds to h colours being required to colour that clique.

We create multiple cliques of decreasing degrees: start with the high-degree cliques and looping until you link up the cliques of degree 2.

```rust
let mut y_idx = 0;
// This for-loop takes the b-vector (which contains how many 2-cliques, 3-cliques, 4-cliques, ..., k-cliques there should be and converts it into multiple tuples like (number of cliques, size of those cliques)
'make_cliques: for (num_cliques, clique_degree) in b_vec.into_iter().zip((1..(k + 1)).into_iter()).rev() {
    if clique_degree <= 1 {
        break;
    }
```

For each clique of size `clique_degree` that we want to create:

```rust
    for clique_idx in 0..num_cliques {
        // Create a clique with nodes indexed y_idx to y_idx+clique_degree
        for i in 0..clique_degree {
            for j in (i + 1)..clique_degree {
```

Go through the randomly-selected nodes, and attempt to connect them together

```rust
                let a = node_indices[y_i[y_idx + i]];
                let b = node_indices[y_i[y_idx + j]];
```

If we've already added this edge => don't add it again

```rust
                if graph.contains_edge(a, b) {
                    continue;
                }
```

Note that in my testing, Leighton's method would add edges to a node even if it already had the maximum number of edges. So here I check if either of the candidate nodes already have the maximum number of neighbours, and if it does, I don't add this edge.

```rust
                if graph.neighbors(b).count() == k || graph.neighbors(a).count() == k {
                    continue;
                }
```

Now that we know it's a valid edge, actually add it:

```rust
                graph.add_edge(a, b, Edge {});
```

If we've reached the maximum number of edges => stop adding edges

```rust
                if graph.edge_count() == num_edges {
                    print!("Have enough edges, exiting");
                    break 'make_cliques;
                }
            }
        }
        y_idx += clique_degree;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps! Maybe someone can convert the rust to ruby. The full, running code is available on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ef6c1c7a947fddfce496f6303b687c7).

#### Example output with `m=84035, n=10, k=5, c=6859, a=8401, b_vec: [0, 1, 1, 3, 6]`

[Link to Dotgraph visualisation](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#graph%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%200%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%201%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%202%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%203%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%204%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%205%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%206%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%207%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%208%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%209%20%5B%20label%20%3D%20%22Node%22%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%200%20--%201%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%201%20--%202%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%202%20--%203%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%203%20--%204%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%204%20--%205%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%205%20--%206%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%206%20--%207%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%207%20--%208%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%208%20--%209%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%209%20--%203%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%209%20--%207%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%209%20--%201%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%209%20--%200%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%203%20--%207%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%203%20--%201%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%207%20--%201%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%208%20--%202%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%208%20--%200%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%202%20--%200%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%204%20--%206%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%204%20--%200%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%205%20--%202%20%5B%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%204%20--%208%20%5B%20%5D%0A%7D)

```
Values: m=84035, n=10, k=5, c=6859, a=8401, b_vec: [0, 1, 1, 3, 6]
Making 6 cliques of degree 5
Making 3 cliques of degree 4
Making 1 cliques of degree 3
Making 1 cliques of degree 2
Making 0 cliques of degree 1
Dotstring of graph:
graph {
    0 [ label = "Node" ]
    1 [ label = "Node" ]
    2 [ label = "Node" ]
    3 [ label = "Node" ]
    4 [ label = "Node" ]
    5 [ label = "Node" ]
    6 [ label = "Node" ]
    7 [ label = "Node" ]
    8 [ label = "Node" ]
    9 [ label = "Node" ]
    0 -- 1 [ ]
    1 -- 2 [ ]
    2 -- 3 [ ]
    3 -- 4 [ ]
    4 -- 5 [ ]
    5 -- 6 [ ]
    6 -- 7 [ ]
    7 -- 8 [ ]
    8 -- 9 [ ]
    9 -- 3 [ ]
    9 -- 7 [ ]
    9 -- 1 [ ]
    9 -- 0 [ ]
    3 -- 7 [ ]
    3 -- 1 [ ]
    7 -- 1 [ ]
    8 -- 2 [ ]
    8 -- 0 [ ]
    2 -- 0 [ ]
    4 -- 6 [ ]
    4 -- 0 [ ]
    5 -- 2 [ ]
    4 -- 8 [ ]
}
```